# Visual Studio Code Extension Error Lense gives unexpected warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, eslint

I am using the Visual Studio Code extension Error Lense. So far, it works as expected. However, when I use inline styles, I am getting an unexpected warnin[image: Screenshot Code Editor]

Why is it highlighting the `Inline style: { marginBottom: 10 }`?

Comment: It's coloured as a warning, this makes me think that some other extension you are using (probably a linter) has a rule that is set to notify you when you use inline styles and Error Lens is just picking up the warning and displaying it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jacob Smit for pointing me into the right direction.
Add this to the `.eslintrc.js` file

```
  rules: {
    'react-native/no-inline-styles': 'off',
  },
```